# Windsor Castle IOC and Property Injection not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

As mentioned in the documentation of Castle.Windsor Framework there should be the possibility to resolve a basic class with properties and resolve dependencies by using property injection. I found no solution and the created solution works only for the basic class/object:

```
public class Class5
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Class9 Class9 { get; set; }
}


public class Class9
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Class10 Class10 { get; set; }
}
```

in program:

```
IWindsorContainer castle = new WindsorContainer();

castle.Register(Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.Component.For(typeof(Class5)));

var obj = castle.Resolve<Class5>();

obj.Description = "Hello Class5"; //works fine
```

other dependencies are not created:

```
obj.Class9.Description = "Hello Class9"; // no object instance of Class9 created
```

Does someone have a solution?
The aim is to create only one basic instance of a class and all other instances will be created automatically. Maybe another IOC Framework is better?
The solution should not contain any interfaces or repositories - only a simple solution for this case for the classes.

I already tried Unity and it works fine with InjectionProperty and [Dependency] - Settings, but with IEnumerables or ICollections it ends up in problems, also all unused objects will be saved in database as null reference by using entity framework(!).
With Castle.Windsor that should also be no problem, but I did not find a solution.

Alternative for Class5 with ICollection:

```
public class Class5
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    //public virtual Class9 Class9 {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Class9> Class9{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: DI Containers like Castle Windsor are not meant to create runtime data objects like DTOs, entities and other short lived data objects. DI Containers are meant to build _object graphs_ of _application components_ i.e. classes that contain the application's _behavior_.

Comment: You are not registering anything other than Class5 with the container so Windsor cannot resolve them.

Answer (score 0):

Windsor cannot create an instance of Class9 because you have not registered it.

Answer (score 0):

As already said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43461910/6695901), Castle.Windsor can't create any other class than `Class5` because you don't register any other class.

To do this you can do the following:

```cs
IWindsorContainer castle = new WindsorContainer();

castle.Register(Component.For<Class5>().LifestyleTransient());
castle.Register(Component.For<Class9>().LifestyleTransient());
```

Now when you call `castle.Resolve<Class5>()` you will also get an instance of `Class9`.

If you have more classes to register, I would recommend you to use an `IWindsorInstaller`:

```cs
public class Bootstrapper
{
    public IWindsorContainer BootstrapperContainer()
    {
        IWindsorContainer castle = new WindsorContainer();
        return castle.Install(new Installer());
    }
}

public class Installer : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<Class5>().LifestyleTransient());
        container.Register(Component.For<Class9>().LifestyleTransient());
        //and so on
    }
}
```

Also make sure you use the correct `Lifestyle`. By default Castle.Windsor uses [`LifestyleSingleton()`](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/lifestyles.md#singleton) which may not be the behaviour you want.

For more information about the available lifestyles check the [official documentation](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/lifestyles.md).